# Java String.replaceFirst() issue

Tags: java, replace, printwriter

Hi I'm trying to write code that will read a file that has a poem. It will then change the first "you" in every line with "we". I've been trying to use replaceFirst(), replace(), replaceAll(); however, not a single one has worked in replacing anything.

```
 import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;//imports

public class TextEditorTester 
{
    private static boolean line_change;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
       String line = "";
       File inFile = new File("OldPoem.txt");
       Scanner in = new Scanner(inFile);
       PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("NewPoem.txt");
       while(in.hasNextLine()){
           line = in.nextLine();
           line.replace("you", "we");
           out.println(line);
       }
       out.close();
       File newFile = new File("NewPoem.txt");
       Scanner newOne = new Scanner(newFile);
       System.out.println(newOne.nextLine());
       System.out.println("Expected: Have we ever tried to enter the long black branches of other lives");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `replace` method *returns* the new line, it cannot modify the object on which you call it. So try:

```
line = line.replace("you", "we");
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable in Java. That means they never change. The methods you are calling return new Strings. You need to save them somewhere.

```
line = line.replace("you", "we");
```

You should consult the Javadocs about Strings in Java before asking a question about the methods that act on them. Everything is explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)